# How does Cloudera CDH4 work with Avro?

Tags: mapreduce, cloudera, avro

I am working on some MapR programs. They are usually coded and tested on Apache hadoop on my local machine,
and packaged jar (with dependencies) is uploaded onto our cluster running Cloudera CDH4 (v4.4.1). For both situation, I have different pom.xml files to make packages.

Now I am using Apache Avro to serialize data and current stable version 1.7.5 is involved.
In local mode, I have **avro-mapred** pom.xml dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and it works well on Apache hadoop.

In cluster mode, for the pom.xml dependency, 
a *classifier* tag is appended as suggested by [CDH4 doc](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.3.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_26_5.html):

```
<classifier>hadoop1</classifier>
```

But with neither hadoop1 or hadoop2, error occurs.
For hadoop1 tag:

```
Error running child : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(AvroKeyOutputFormat.java:87)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

For hadoop2 tag,

```
Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.createDatumWriter(Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;)Lorg/apache/avro/io/DatumWriter;
at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.<init>(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:53)
at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat$RecordWriterFactory.create(AvroKeyOutputFormat.java:78)
at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(AvroKeyOutputFormat.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

I am programming using new **mapreduce** interface in MapR1. 
I also guess its a conflict with the installed avro version and further contact with our cluster admin
will be reached.
Any ideas, guys?

Jamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you are developing against a very different version of Hadoop than you are running against. CDH 4.4 comes in an "MR1" and "MR2" flavor, with newer "MR2" being the default. I think you are probably compiling against a Hadoop 1.x distribution? You don't need to compile against CDH libraries (although that's the best idea here), but if I'm right here, you will at least need to compile against Hadoop 2.x.

Your Avro is fine except that you then need to not specify "hadoop1" either.

Or, if you really intend to use MR1, you need to make sure you have actually set up an MR1 cluster in CDH 4.4. This means installed in the 'mapreduce' service instead of 'yarn' and using Maven artifacts with "...-mr1-..." in the name.

Comment: Hi Sean, Its not solved yet. I am actually compiling against MR1 using new mapreduce APIs and our CDH 4.4.1 is also configured with MR1. I have some other programs without avro running successfully on the cluster. Because avro is not shipped with CDH manager by default, it is installed manully later. Maybe I need some troubleshooting on this installing progress..

Comment: It does look like the problem is Avro. Avro is a library so doesn't have a place per se in Cloudera Manager. It is part of Hadoop and thus part of CDH. I've just realized you said Avro 1.7.5; I do remember some problem when updating from 1.7.4 to 1.7.5 that prevented me from updating, but I don't think it was this. I would advise you to match the version is CDH / Hadoop, directly, which I think is 1.7.4. This error shows the Avro is built for Hadoop 1 but is encountering Hadoop 2.

Comment: Its a start for me to try avro so the latest version is utilized. I will try ur advice and give a match on these two versions.

Comment: Sean, its solved. The version problem. I replace the avro-mapred of 1.7.5 with 1.7.4, set the classifier tag as hadoop2; and only this settings works. The hadoop1 tag also raises error shown like above. Now I am more confused with CDF structrue. I use MR1 + mapreduce API + avro-mapred(hadoop2) running successfully on CDH cluster configured as MR1. Maybe this thread should appear in CDH user list.

Comment: Yes the many branches of Hadoop have made quite a mess. The problem is that even MR1 changed from Hadoop 1 to 2 in small ways like exactly what you see. It works at compile-time without code change but the resulting compiled code is not compatible with 1 and 2 at the same time!

Answer (score 2):

```
           ` <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
      <version>${avro.version}</version>
      <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    </dependency>`
```

This did the magic!!
Its the issue with hadoop2 and hadoop1

refer - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1170

Above was for cloudera

And for MapR amazon

`
      org.apache.avro
      avro-mapred
      ${avro.version}

```
          <avro.version>1.7.6</avro.version>
 <hadoop.version> 1.0.3-mapr-2.1.3.1</hadoop.version>`
```

These did it...Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a version confilct.  The CDH supported Avro version is currently 1.7.3.  I had this same issue with 1.7.5, which was solved by changing the version.

From the CDH docs: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/CDH4-Installation-Guide.html#../CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_26_5.html

Comment: CDH 4.4 comes with Avro 1.7.4. 1.7.3 would probably also work.